# Should I worry about repeating commit logs following rebase upstream/master?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-log

I'm a git newbie, and can't find the answer to my issue elsewhere. Apologies if it's a rather basic question.

So:
I've forked from a project, and then cloned my fork.
I've set my remotes up so that I have the upstream (originalproject/sitename.git) and an origin (myfork/sitename.git).
I've created a branch from my local master and I've been working in this branch. In the meantime, there have been updates on the upstream.

So I checked from my branch back into my local master and:
`(master)$ git fetch upstream

(master)$ git rebase upstream/master`

However, when I `git log` to check that I've got the latest upstream commits, it lists the same git commits tens of times over - so it lists commit logs from 6 weeks ago to now, then a semi-colon, then it lists the commit logs from 7 weeks ago to now, then a semi-colon, then it lists commits logs from 8 weeks ago to now, and so on.

My question is this:
Should I be worried about these repeating commit logs?
If I shouldn't be worried, to get the branch which I'd been working in up to date, do I then just 'git checkout branchname' and then 'git rebase master'?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: first try `git log @{u}..HEAD` (or replace @{u} with upstream/master) and see which commits are being repeated.  If it's your local commits you have a problem, if it's the upstream commits then you have a problem somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for the response @AndrewC, it's much appreciated. The commits which are being repeated are the upstream commits, so I think I have a problem elsewhere - if anyone has an idea of where that problem might stem from, I'm all ears! Thanks again,

Comment: Next step is to check your repo on github and see if the commits are on it or not.

Comment: Have you tried `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` to understand how the commits are *repeated*? Are they on the same branch?